# Getting User Input and Calculating Hypotenuse

Tags: javascript, html

The code below should calculate the Pythagorean theorem. However, if the user puts `3` and `4` in the input fields and presses the button, the result does not show up. Could you help me find what's wrong?

```js
function compute(form){
    A=eval(form.a.value)
    B=eval(form.b.value)
    with (Math){
        C=sqrt(((pow(a,2)+pow(b,2))))};
    form.result.value=C;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <pre>
        This program will calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle
        Side 1 <input type="text" name="a" size=15>

        Side 2 <input type="text" name="b" size=15>

        Hypotenuse <input type="text" name="result" size=15>

        <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="compute(this.form)">
        </pre>
    </form>
```

Comment: I am having a hard time to understand what you want. What this form should do? What is the unexpected behavior (that makes it "wrong")?

Comment: what the form is supposed to do is take user input in boxes, lets say i input 3 and 4, and go through the Pythagorean theorem, and put the result of that in a result box. If I put in 3 and 4, the box for Hypotenuse should say 5, but nothing ever comes up -- im sorry if that doesn't make any sense, our instructions were not that clear either

Comment: As a side note (If your teacher didn't tell that to you already): You pretty much never use `eval` on user input (and in general there are rarely use cases for it). It could lead to security issues if used without caution

Comment: I've editted the question, Mari, in order to simplify it and make it more objective. Please review if it fits your desire.

Comment: thank you so much, it does make it more clear. I suppose keeping things simple does make it better haha, and A_A, no he did not tell us that! The class is a mess, haha, I should tell my classmates that. We all think our teacher doesn't know what he's doing and its making us nuts, we just wanted to learn to code.

Comment: And use of `with` [is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). TBH, this is the first time I've even seen it

Comment: @A_A the link you provided explains that OP's is the correct use of with (very close example).

Comment: @LelioFaieta The MDN link explains the use of `with`, but starts with "Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.". And later on explains that it's not even allowed in "strict mode".  So I'd definitely not recommend `with`, even if correctly used (and instead just use `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow`)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive, so after defining `A` one cannot access it by the lower case `a`.

Replacing `A` with a lower case `a` works

```js
function compute(form) {
  a = eval(form.a.value)
  b = eval(form.b.value)
  with(Math) {
    C = sqrt(((pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2))))
  };
  form.result.value = C;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <pre>
        This program will calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle
        Side 1 <input type="text" name="a" size=15>

        Side 2 <input type="text" name="b" size=15>

        Hypotenuse <input type="text" name="result" size=15>

        <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="compute(this.form)">
        </pre>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I was agonizing over what was wrong in our given code, of course it was something so miniscule

Answer (score 0):

You used `a` in the calcule instead of `A`, the variable you created before. Javascript is case sensitive, so `var test` is different of `var Test`.

In your case, just replace:

```js
with (Math){
    C=sqrt(((pow(a,2)+pow(b,2))))};
```

To this:

```js
with(Math){
    var C = sqrt( ( (pow(A ,2)+pow(B, 2)) ) );
};
```

Also, you should search how to organize your codes, thats make these simplier error easy to fix and avoid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <pre>
            This program will calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle
            Side 1 <input type="text" name="a" size=15>

            Side 2 <input type="text" name="b" size=15>

            Hypotenuse <input type="text" name="result" size=15>

            <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="compute(this.form)">
            </pre>
        </form>

    <script>
        function compute(form){
            var A = eval(form.a.value);
            var B = eval(form.b.value);
            
            with(Math){
                var C = sqrt( ( (pow(A ,2)+pow(B, 2)) ) );
            };
            
            form.result.value = C;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```